# After coming back from sleep, ubuntu's GUI restarted

Tags: 14.04, kernel, compiz, suspend, syslog

My laptop was in sleep mode for the night, and in the morning it couldn't get up, but instead sent me (after a while) to the welcome screen, closing every program that was running (that I know of).

Clearly, I went to see the `syslog`, and indeed there were a couple of warnings/errors/failures there.

Here are a few:

```
Jun 26 09:39:51 lati kernel: [152504.094113] ACPI Error: Index value 0x0000000000000083 overflows field width 0x7 (20140424/exfldio-343)
Jun 26 09:39:51 lati kernel: [152504.094116] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\NEVT] (Node ffff88040e047258), AE_AML_REGISTER_LIMIT (20140424/psparse-536)
Jun 26 09:39:51 lati kernel: [152504.094119] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.ECDV._Q66] (Node ffff88040e044b90), AE_AML_REGISTER_LIMIT (20140424/psparse-536)
```

(These are probably related to [Dell e7440, sleep sometimes fails, kernel logs show ACPI errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/606640/dell-e7440-sleep-sometimes-fails-kernel-logs-show-acpi-errors))

Then these ones:

```
Jun 26 09:39:51 lati kernel: [152504.467188] ata2.00: failed to get NCQ Send/Recv Log Emask 0x1
Jun 26 09:39:51 lati kernel: [152504.467571] ata2.00: failed to get NCQ Send/Recv Log Emask 0x1
```

(Perhaps related to [Fail message during boot. Can I delay boot or how do I solve it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/735039/fail-message-during-boot-can-i-delay-boot-or-how-do-i-solve-it))

Then these ones:

```
Jun 26 09:39:51 lati bluetoothd[718]: Unknown command complete for opcode 19
Jun 26 09:39:51 lati bluetoothd[718]: hci0: Set Secure Simple Pairing (0x000b) failed: Busy (0x0a)
```

(Related to [bluetoothd fails at "set secure simple pairing"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/791264/bluetoothd-fails-at-set-secure-simple-pairing))

Then again ACPI errors:

```
Jun 26 09:39:54 lati kernel: [152508.018847] ACPI Error: Index value 0x0000000000000083 overflows field width 0x7 (20140424/exfldio-343)
Jun 26 09:39:54 lati kernel: [152508.018858] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\NEVT] (Node ffff88040e047258), AE_AML_REGISTER_LIMIT (20140424/psparse-536)
Jun 26 09:39:54 lati kernel: [152508.018869] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.ECDV._Q66] (Node ffff88040e044b90), AE_AML_REGISTER_LIMIT (20140424/psparse-536)
```

Then some `compiz` error:

```
Jun 26 09:40:02 lati kernel: [152515.489573] traps: compiz[2396] general protection ip:7ff4391c4c34 sp:7ffeff248248 error:0 in libframe.so.6.0.0[7ff4391bf000+1c000]
```

And a couple of these:

```
Jun 26 09:40:02 lati NetworkManager[811]: <info> Unmanaged Device found; state CONNECTED forced. (see http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/191889)
```

(Related: [What does it mean "unmanaged device"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/791350/what-does-it-mean-unmanaged-device))

And then an error in the network manager:

```
Jun 26 09:40:20 lati NetworkManager[811]: <error> [1466923220.217192] [nm-system.c:1266] nm_system_replace_default_ip6_route(): (wlan2): failed to set IPv6 default route: -7
```

(Related: [NetworkManager fails to set IPv6 default route](https://askubuntu.com/questions/791263/networkmanager-fails-to-set-ipv6-default-route))

And then something kills compiz:

```
Jun 26 09:40:26 lati gnome-session[2211]: WARNING: Application 'compiz.desktop' killed by signal 11
Jun 26 09:40:26 lati gnome-session[2211]: WARNING: App 'compiz.desktop' respawning too quickly
Jun 26 09:40:26 lati gnome-session[2211]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
```

(Possibly related: [GUI restarts after wake up from suspend or boot ('Application 'compiz.desktop' killed ..)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/626708/gui-restarts-after-wake-up-from-suspend-or-boot-application-compiz-desktop-k), ["CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/662678/critical-we-failed-but-the-fail-whale-is-dead-sorry))

Then

```
Jun 26 09:40:26 lati bluetoothd[718]: hci0: Remove UUID (0x0011) failed: Busy (0x0a)
```

Then

```
Jun 26 09:40:31 lati NetworkManager[811]: <warn> error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.open: (3) GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get UID of name ':1.193218': no such name
```

(Related: [NameHasNoOwner warning at NetworkManager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/685397/namehasnoowner-warning-at-networkmanager))

Then

```
Jun 26 09:40:33 lati signond[1015]: ../../../../src/signond/signondaemon.cpp 388 init Failed to SUID root. Secure storage will not be available.
```

(Perhaps related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/signon/+bug/1182007)

And finally:

```
Jun 26 09:41:02 lati gnome-session[694]: GLib-CRITICAL: g_environ_setenv: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
```

(Possibly related: [Dell e7440, sleep sometimes fails, kernel logs show ACPI errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/606640/dell-e7440-sleep-sometimes-fails-kernel-logs-show-acpi-errors))

Quite a lot of errors, but the result is a restart, which is the real bad consequence of all of this.

I kept a copy of the `syslog`, in case you think anything there might be used to help analyse this issue.

---

My system info:

- Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (trusty)
- Architecture: 64 bit
- Kernel version: 3.16.0-40-generic
- Dell E7440
- Bios version: A14

Comment: @PeterMortensen, sure, `/var/log/syslog`.